# Dynamic Retrofit baseurl from discovery in Clean Architecture

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I have a project following Clean Architecture design principles, and making retrofit requests (in my remote data layer, called by a repository layer which switches between local and remote datasources).

Everything was for the best, but one of my new features is to make the baseUrl of my Retrofit requests dynamic, the base url coming from a discovery over the network. 
Once the discovery is done, the chosen source server url is stored and should be used until a new discovery is requested by the user.

I've seen that I can make the baseUrl dynamic in different ways (using an OkHttp or the @Url parameter), but how should I "cleanly" pass it once and for all to my remote class? Should it even be stored there once, or should it be passed in each request (uck)?
Should I combine Usecases to first get my baseurl, then pass it to the repository for each request (uck uck)?

I'm also using Dagger2 and my project is vaguely based on this boilerplate: https://github.com/bufferapp/android-clean-architecture-boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this](https://github.com/JessYanCoding/RetrofitUrlManager) library. It allows you to change url directly in Retrofit dynamically.  `RetrofitUrlManager.getInstance().setGlobalDomain("your BaseUrl");`